# Memory Error due to a lot of Categories

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

I am working on text classification problem. Here is my dataset

```
Narration                               | Category
_________________________________________________________                             
clg cr: ten plus                        |transfer to ten plus
At Sydney, Garment payment BY Mr.Haj    |Transfer From Mr.Haj
RTGS-CPU Wales-Steven                   |Transfer from Steven
NEFT-Payment-Amy Adams/12march/XXXX4567 |Transfer from Amy Adams
KFC Chicken Burger                      |Food
Trent Wines and Rum                     |Alcohol
CD-Payment-2345XXX78 Imran              |Transfer from Imran
     .                                     .
     .                                     .
     .                                     .
```

The problem is I have huge volume of data-set to train, (around 3 million entries) as a result there are lot of categories formed (around 500k categories) It is not possible for me to train the machine with so many categories. The problem is with the individual transfer, Example in the dataset: (Transfer From Mr.Haj, Transfer from Steven, ......)
I don't want to loose significance of narrations too as a result I dont want to generalise as "Transfer to XX" instead of party name.

My two questions are:
1. How do I train the data with so many categories.
2. How Do I handle the party name while testing (Example: Mr.Haj, Steven) with similar kind of test narration data and get the categorized output as Transfer to Customer.

part of my script:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
data= pd.read_csv('file.txt', delimiter='\t',usecols=['Narration','Category'],encoding=("utf-8"))
target_one=data['Category']
test_data= pd.read_csv('test_file.txt', delimiter='\t',usecols=['Narration','Category'],encoding=("utf-8"))

x_train, y_train = (data.Narration, data.Category )
x_test, y_test = (test_data.details, test_data.category)

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2),stop_words='english')
X_train = vect.fit_transform(x_train)
X_test = vect.transform(x_test)

mnb = MultinomialNB(alpha =0.13)
mnb.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: you can try to train the data with binomial classification e.g data belongs to category X or not, and train it N times, where N is the different  categories, each iteration on different category, basically you have N models, but keep in mind that when classifying new data you will have to pass it through those N models and choose the best one

Comment: [Here is an example of "out of core classification"](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html)